# Calculate tkinter window width based on title length

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I calculate  and set the width of a `tkinter.Frame`-derived window based on the window's title length?
I.e., could someone help me out with the with the **`width = ???`**-expression in the the code below? (well aware of that the result depends on the font being used, system buttons, etc.)

Thanks in advance
/Harald

```
import Tkinter as tkinter #Python 2

class MyFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, *args, **kw):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
            # Calculate the frame width ensuring that the entire title is shown
            # using len(title)
            width = ???
            self.master.config(width = width)
            self.master.title(title)

mf = MyFrame("Some Frame Title")
mf.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this based on the window title. The display (and thus the width) is controlled by the window manager. The only way you can do this is if you know for certain what font is being used in the title bar. In that case you can use the `measure1` method of a font object to compute the width of a string in that specific font. Even with that, you need to know what extra decorations the window manager might use and account for that, and this is different for every window manager.